# setter error in flutter while assigning value to class variable In flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a demo where I am storing data in divide using sqfliteHelper and I want to create a object list to store data in memory for temporary use but I am getting error while assigning value to class variable, regarding setter required

here is my code

```
class SqfliteProvider {
  List<CategoryModel> _categorylist = [];

  List<CategoryModel> get categories {
    return _categorylist;
  }

  

  static Future<List<CategoryModel>?> fetchcategory() async {
    final db = await _getdb();

   
    List<CategoryModel> templist = [];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist = await db.query('categorytb');

    if (maplist.isEmpty) return null;

    templist = maplist.map((e) => CategoryModel.frommap(e)).toList();


//this statement showing an error ...required setter..
    _categorylist = templist;
    return templist;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're accessing object property via static function.

Comment: how to correct if I want to keep static

Comment: Just remove `_categorylist = templist;` from your code. I don't think you need to save it when you're accessing the function directly from the caller. Better to remove the side effect in your code.